# Writing a Firefox/Netscape plugin

Tags: firefox, npapi

I am in the process of writing a Firefox/Netscape plugin (not extension) to run on windows, and I was wondering if you could suggest any sites for guidance and tutorials?

I have been looking through the Mozilla documentation, specifically the gecko sdk documentations for a reference, but it's not the easiest to follow.

Just wondering if there are any good sites out there for helping with this? Or will I need to rely on the Mozilla docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for NPAPI (Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface). Here are some results:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI
- http://gplflash.sourceforge.net/gplflash2_blog/npapi.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** the following are for making EXTENSIONS, not plugins. Sorry.

- http://lifehacker.com/264490/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension
- http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/08/how-to-create-firefox-extensions/

Both have helped me in the past.

Comment: He asks for plugins (like Apple QuickTime), not extensions.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using Nixysa, it's new http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/. It abstracts away the details of NPAPI. Plus, it has a working sample. The website describes it best:

> Nixysa is a framework written in
>   Python to automatically generate glue
>   code for NPAPI plugins (plugins for
>   browsers such as Google Chrome or
>   Firefox), letting you easily expose
>   C++ classes to Javascript from a
>   simple IDL representation.  Nixysa was
>   originally conceived for the needs of
>   O3D, but is flexible enough to support
>   a wide range of use cases.
>
> Check out the code following the
>   instructions here and try the sample
>   in examples/complex.

You can write a program that can register and invoke a Javascript callback too.

One caveat is that there is no documentation (thus far).

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that works cross-browser (firefox and ie) and/or cross-platform (windows, linux, mac), you could look at firebreath:
http://www.firebreath.org

It is quite stable and has a lot of great features.

For general "getting started" information, I have a few blog posts on the subject (linked to from some of the above sources as well)

http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/